# unable to send value from one javascript function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to pass parameter value from one javascript function to another.

From Below Code: i am passing two values from function `formatLink` to function `openDialog` .But only the first value(`cellvalue`) is passing correctly but the send value (`para`) is not passing .
Why i it is not passing to function openDialog?
Please help me

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function formatLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject)
    {
         var para=image.jpg; 
         return "<a style='cursor:pointer;' onClick='javascript:openDialog("+cellvalue+"),("+para+")'><img width='63' height='25' src='<s:url action='ImageAction' namespace='/myimage/secure'></s:url>" + "?imageId="+para+ "'></a>";
      }

    function openDialog(cellvalue,para) { 
        alert(para);//this is coming as undefine
            alert(cellvalue);//& this values is coming correctly

         //below diaologbox id is given to open
             $("#employees_details").load("<s:property value="loadformurl"/>?themeid="+employee);
            $("#employees_details").dialog('open');
    }
```

Comment: try `javascript:openDialog("+cellvalue+","+para+")` instead of `javascript:openDialog("+cellvalue+"),("+para+")`

Comment: @micha i tried but its not comming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some extra parentheses in your generated function call:

change

```
return "<a style='cursor:pointer;' onClick='javascript:openDialog("+cellvalue+"), ("+para+")'><img width='63' height='25' src='<s:url action='ImageAction' namespace='/myimage/secure'></s:url>" + "?imageId="+para+ "'></a>";
```

to

```
return "<a style='cursor:pointer;' onClick='openDialog(\'"+cellvalue+"\', \'"+para+"\')'><img width='63' height='25' src='<s:url action='ImageAction' namespace='/myimage/secure'></s:url>" + "?imageId="+para+ "'></a>";
```

Notice, I removed the ending and beginning parentheses in the onClick handler and fixed some quotes:

```
onClick='openDialog(\'"+cellvalue+"\', \'"+para+"\')'
```

**UPDATE**

Answer is best shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sHQEn/

Comment: I'd get rid of the javascript protocol while you're there :x

Comment: @swatkins i tried but on click its not calling my the function `openDialog`  Why?

Comment: @swatkins I checked in browser by doing inspect element i am getting like this `<a onclick="openDialog(" 72',="" 'penguins.jpg')'=""><img width="63" height="25" src="/visionbooks/myimage/secure/ImageAction?imageId=Penguins.jpg"></a>`

Comment: @AshutoshSingh - I put this in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/sHQEn/) - had to change the code around a bit, but this should help to get it to work.